# Using _endthread();

Tags: c++, multithreading

Today I started working on a project where I need use thread's, I'm using functions from process.h: _beginthread and _endthread.

My question is, I really need use _endthread(); at the end of function?

```
void LGThread(void *null_ptr) {
 /* ... code ...*/
 _endthread();
}
void main() {
 _beginthread(LGThread, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Or even with:

```
void LGThread(void *null_ptr) {
 /* ... code ...*/
}
void main() {
 _beginthread(LGThread, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I'm fine? What it does specially?

Comment: std::thread is much better than raw win32 or CRT api's

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31257350/6364089

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need it. And in a C++ program it can be harmfull: It does not return, so destructors will not be called for objects allocated on the stack in the thread function.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Windows functions. In C++, the standard is `std::thread` from `<thread>`.

That said, you don't need `_endthread` just like you don't need `exit(0)`. Just returning is sufficient.
[edit]
Scott has a point, returning is even better as that does run destructors. I.e. `_endthread` is actually more like `abort()`.